# How to right align content of pbox?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, errors, boxes

Lets have simple `\pbox` example like this:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage{pbox, calc}
\begin{document}
\noindent\fbox{\pbox{\textwidth}{Some text\\Text}}
\end{document}
```

Here is printed result:

[image]

I want that `Text` on second line to be alighned right. I tried to adjust previous code so that it reads:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage{pbox, calc}
\begin{document}
\noindent\fbox{\pbox{\textwidth}{\begin{flushright}Some text\\Text\end{flushright}}}
\end{document}
```

When trying to compile it I'm getting following error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.
```

Even with the error there is still some output but it is not entirely correct (too big box margins):

[image]

How can I correctly right align content of `pbox`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage{pbox, calc}
\def\flushRight{\leftskip0pt plus 1fill\rightskip0pt}
\begin{document}
\noindent\fbox{\pbox{\textwidth}{\flushRight Some text\\Text}}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\RaggedLeft` from `ragged2e` package.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage{pbox,ragged2e}
\begin{document}
\noindent\fbox{\pbox{\textwidth}{\RaggedLeft Some text\\Text}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Works in this simple example but does not when content of `\pbox` is more complex.

Comment: @drasto Can you show a code where this is not working?

Comment: I would like to but I'm afraid I cannot :( Licencing issues. I tried to isolate the cause and post some example but it is taking too much time - code that creates content of `\pbox` is rather complex. Anyway, solution from @JLDiaz answer works well.